# How to publish and disconnect without having to resort to setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, rabbitmq

In the documentation of RabbitMQ they give an example of publishing a message to an exchange and then closing the connection after a 500 delay using `setTimeout`. I decided to skip the `setTimeout`, but then my messages were not being sent to the RabbitMQ server if I closed the connection immediately after I ran the `publish` method. Imagine:

```js
channel.publish('MyExchange', 'MyRoutingKey', Buffer.from('{}'));
await channel.close();
await connection.close();
```

Is there a better way to close the connection after sending a message than setting a `setTimeout`?

Link to documentation, at the `Putting it all together` section: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-javascript.html

Comment: Can you provide a link to said example? That would help.

Comment: Does `channel.publish()` return a promise that you can `await` by any chance?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi it does not, neither the `amqplib` implementation nor the `amqplib/callback_api` implementation provide a way of knowing if the message has been sent. They are both synchronous and only return `true` or `false` if they were able to write the message to a buffer.

Comment: How about a way to listen for published messages, then you would only close if you see that the message has been in fact sent? (I am no expert here just brainstorming ideas)

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi The message is being sent to another system, so to implement such a listener would involve send a message back to the system which has sent the message. In the case that I'd send back the message I'd need to resort to a RPC kind of scheme, which I don't want to do.

Comment: @Enthys Thanks for providing a link. Unfortunately I can't get _any_ useful information from it as I was hoping. You might be better off asking in a rabbitmq forum or on their issue tracking system / mailing list. I don't think you'll get (as this question hasn't really gotten any activity) a satisfying answer here in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have also provided the connection and channel instantiation to the question above.

The solution was to use `createConfirmChannel` instead of `createChannel`. The `Channel` returned by `createConfirmChannel` provides a `waitForConfirms` method which waits to `confirm` that all messages were received by the server.

For a more in-depth explanation:

- https://rabbitmq.com/publishers.html#data-safety
- https://github.com/amqp-node/amqplib/blob/main/examples/waitForConfirms.js